# Does a SQL Server bit column really use a whole byte worth of space?

Tags: sql-server, datatypes

I was poking around SSMS and noticed the "size" of my `INT` columns were 4 bytes (expected) but I was a bit shocked to see my `BIT` columns were a whole byte.

Did I misunderstand what I was looking at?

Comment: I'd feel lucky that BIT columns are aligned on a byte boundary instead of a word boundary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How many bit columns do you have defined in the table? I found this on MSDN, it says 8 or less bit columns are stored as one byte.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: Accepted for MSDN source which I failed to locate. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Yes.

If you only have one `bit` column in the table then storage uses a `byte` but up to 8 `bit` columns can be stored in the same byte so the next 7 are "free" in that respect.

There is also a 1 bit per column storage need for the `NULL_BITMAP` (again rounded up to the next byte). In the data pages this contains a `bit` for all columns irrespective of whether or not they allow `NULL` (with [the exception](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%28630%29-three-null-bitmap-myths.aspx) of nullable columns added later as a metadata only change via `ALTER TABLE` where the row has not yet been updated)

Answer (score 9):

`BIT` uses one byte per row, but you can pack up to 8 `BIT` fields into that one byte storage.

So the first field costs one byte, but the next seven are **free**!